# dictionary error item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to read every `#define` in a C++ header, and display an editor for each of the values, so I can quickly redefine the constants.

I'm trying to parse the file, getting each item on the left side to be key. I want to display the value on the left, edit the values and save back out. Currently, when I save my file it messes up the format.

This is the code i currently have :

```
private String header;
private Dictionary<String, String> tokens;
private String file = Properties.Settings.Default.path_location;
public TextBox elf_naparm_zombie_developer;

public harrs_gsh_editor(string file)//TextBox elf_naparm_zombie_developer
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.path_location = file;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    loadweapon();
   // this.elf_naparm_zombie_developer = elf_naparm_zombie_developer;
}

public void loadweapon()
{
    this.tokens = File.ReadLines(this.file)
        .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, @"^\s*#define\s+(.+?)(\s+(.+?))?((\s*//)|$)"))
        .Where(m => m.Success && m.Groups[3].Success)
        .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[3].Value);
}

public String Search(String name)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> pair in tokens)
    {
        if (pair.Key == name)
            return pair.Value;
    }

    return null;
}

public void Set(String key, String val)
{
    tokens[key] = val;
}

public void Save(String file)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(file)))
    {
        sw.Write(header);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> pair in tokens)
        {
            sw.Write("\r\n" + pair.Key + "#define       " + pair.Value);
        }
    }
}

public void Save()
{
    this.Save(file);
}
```

The issue I have is when I save it back, it messes up the file and removes the #define. What im trying to do is just change the value and write it back to the program with changed value

this is the [file i want to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcVX0.png)

So what im trying to do is load up the selected key and display the value witch i have managed to do with this code i created but the issue im having is writing it back

the code i use to load and populate the text box

```
namespace Harry_s_Template_Editor
```

{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    harrs_gsh_editor elfghc;
    string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"/hb21_zm_ai_napalm.gsh";



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        elfghc = new harrs_gsh_editor(path);//TextBox elf_naparm_zombie_developer
        elf_naparm_zombie_developer = elf_naparm_zombie_developer;
       // MessageBox.Show(path);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        elfghc.loadweapon();
        this.elf_naparm_zombie_developer.Text = elfghc.Search("NAPALM_ZOMBIE_DEVELOPER_DEBUG_PRINTS");
        elfghc.Set("NAPALM_ZOMBIE_DEVELOPER_DEBUG_PRINTS", elf_naparm_zombie_developer.Text);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        elfghc.Set("NAPALM_ZOMBIE_DEVELOPER_DEBUG_PRINTS", elf_naparm_zombie_developer.Text);
        elfghc.Save(path);
    }
}
```

}

when i save out the file i now get this error when i try to load the program again
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcVX0.png)

thanks in advance Yuki

[file when saved back](https://pastebin.com/sR8cVHgn)

Comment: Please supply a [mcve]

Comment: You are also missing the class definitions for the code above, could you please add that in? Even if it's just `public class Form1 : Form` at the top of the code, it is helpful to see

Comment: Why are you writing it back to the file in this order: `sw.Write("\r\n" + pair.Key + "#define       " + pair.Value);`?  Shouldn't the `#define` come first on the line after `\r\n`?  I would have thought it should be something like this: `sw.Write("\r\n#define " + pair.Key + "      " + pair.Value);`

Comment: yeah that managed to fix the issue i was having the only problem though it removes all credits and stuff like that and ruins all the format of it here is the write back to it https://pastebin.com/sR8cVHgn  as you can see form the other one it removes all credits and removes all the beginning stuff form it

Comment: I would suggest switching to an xml file.  This allows having different categories and .net already has libraries for reading writing  and editing them.  Perhaps the best part, the header information will be in a separate element and can remain untouched when you edit the other parts.  Another advantage, by putting the settings in a class you can de/serialize them directly from and to xml.

Comment: the file is gsh file witch is used for black ops 3 mod tools and i am creating a program or trying to edit functions form program instead of editing file directly so using xml is not a option to me :( i would love to be able to use that but dont have the option to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original answer:**

Why are you writing it back to the file in this order: `sw.Write("\r\n" + pair.Key + "#define " + pair.Value);`? Shouldn't the `#define` come first on the line after `\r\n`? I would have thought it should be something like this: `sw.Write("\r\n#define " + pair.Key + " " + pair.Value);`

**New answer** (the question has changed)

There are two problems with what you are doing:

1. You are writing key/value pairs back to a file, ignoring the headers and credits that were in the original file.  If you're happy to strip those out then that's fine, but it sounds like this is important to you. So instead you need to read the file, find the keys in the file, then update the values and save the updated file back to disk.  That's a harder problem than simply writing a bunch of key/value pairs to a file.
2. The second issue is the way you are writing the file back to disk.  According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx?PHPSESSID=tn8k5...) MSDN page, `File.OpenWrite` has the following behaviour:

> The OpenWrite method opens a file if one already exists for the file
>   path, or creates a new file if one does not exist. For an existing
>   file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead,
>   it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. If you
>   overwrite a longer string (such as “This is a test of the OpenWrite
>   method”) with a shorter string (such as “Second run”), the file will
>   contain a mix of the strings (“Second runtest of the OpenWrite
>   method”).

So this is why you're getting a mangled file. You're overwriting the first N bytes with your updated key/value pairs, and the rest of the file is duplicated data from the original file.  You probably want to use the following instead, which will overwrite the original file entirely:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false))
```

Comment: Notice I am not elaborating on the "harder problem" of search and replace - but there are plenty of existing places you can look for help with this.  I'm simply answering the question of "why is this happening?"

Comment: thank you for quick reply only issue i have is i very new to parsing files i try not to message on forms but not sure how to change this code to work right as new to it i tryied to just change file.openwright to file.writealltext but it errors says takes one argument

Comment: See my update - last line.  Use this instead, sorry, last suggestion was a little confusing

Comment: thank you so much thats fixed the issue :) the credits and that dont matter as users wont see them if they use my program so thank you very much for all your help marked as answer and voted up

Comment: Thanks!  Glad I could help :)